# Is this circuit an FDNR?

Tags: active-filter

I am trying to design frequency dependant negative resistor circuit that is not based on the generalised impedance converter. I have found the GIC based FDNR to be unstable and difficult to understand.

The circuit I have designed is based on an active capacitor circuit. I replaced the resistor with a capacitor, in order to turn the op amp B into a differentiator. The idea is to make the reactance at node a to be a second order differential, instead of the first order differential of the original circuit.

[image]

[image]

It seems to be working. I have used it to implement the equivalent of an un-damped L C low pass filter. Using the FDNR in place of the capacitor and a resistor in place of the inductor. It seems to be more stable than the GIC based FDNR.

[image]

The only problem I have is that as I vary the resistor that is equivalent to the inductor, the resonance changes. The resonance decreases as the resistance increases. This does not happen with the classic GIC circuit.  So my question is why is the the resonance changing as I vary the 'inductance' resistor, is this because I don't have a true FDNR?

Comment: Just a suggestion: people in other countries (like me) are not used to abbreviations like GIC, FDNR, so please just write the full terms, if you really want to encourage others to help out.

Answer (score 1):

The GIC based FDNR is one of the classical blocks for realizing active filters.
If you are using Antoniou`s GIC structure you will have no stability problems.

Regarding your last figure: An FDNR NEVER can replace a filter. It works - like a resistor - as a grounded one-port and must be combined with other passive parts (using BRUTON`s impedance transformation).

**UPDATE**: The block as shown in the second figure (two opamps) is an ideal diffentiator because the feedback capacitor has no influence (feedback voltage is shorted due to the voltage source connected at the feedback node.

If you combine this circuit with a resistor (last figure), you have one of the classical realizations of a second-order bandpass (output at the 2nd opamp) or a second-order lowpass (output at the 1st opamp).

There is no relationship to any FDNR structure.

Comment: In my last figure, the FDNR is combined with a resistor. The resistor simulates an inductor, I have tried Antoniou's GIC, it is unstable for my application. Which is to make a simulation of an LC low pass filter with high resonance and a tunable resonant frequency over a vide range.

Comment: Nick, I am involved in active filters since more than 20 years - however, I never have heard about stability problems with Antoniou`s GIC. Are you sure that the reason for the observed problems is the GIC block? I doubt.

Comment: Nick, see my update.

Comment: Antoniou's GIC was very difficult for me to get it not to rf oscillate. The problem seems to be dependent on which op amp is used. TL070s work best, I tried may other more expensive types. I spoke to another guy who was having the same problem.

Comment: I saw you update, I am not feeding it with a voltage source. I am feeding it from a resistive impedance. When I do, it is behaving like an R/FDNR filter equivalent to an L/C filter. See figure 3

Comment: Are you aware that 3 FDNR alternatives are possible with Antoniou`s block? Did you check all three? More than that: If your aim is to realize a 2nd order filter- why do you want a GIC realization? Normally, this method is used for higher orders only.

Comment: Yes, the most stable was z1 as c, z2 as r, z3 as r, z4 as r, z5 as c

Comment: Feeding the two-opamp block with a "resistive impedance" is identical with a series resistance and an ideal voltage source (my assumption as mentioned under UPDATE). In this case, you have a second-order RC filter. Thats all!. If you like, you can compare the transfer function with the same function obtained using an L-C filter or an R-FDNR filter. All these filters can have the same behaviour. BUT IN YOUR CASE IT IS NOT A REALIZATION BASED ON THE FDNR PRINCIPLE.

Comment: Yes - I agree to the components z1...z5 as mentioned by you (best selection).

Comment: I can't find any information online about the practical implementation of the FDNR. Only the theory. Do you know of any books or other info?

Comment: "Practical implementation"? It is the well-known two-opamp block introduced by Antoniou! What kind of additional information are you looking for?

Comment: I guess I have probably figured out the best order of z1-z5 and the best op amp to use. I am just interested to know the only way for me to do this was by trial and error.

Comment: As I have mentioned, three different options are possible for realizing an FDNR based on the GIC block. Extensive reasearch activities have shown that the "best" solution is with Y1=sC1 and Y5=sC5 and R2=R3. In this case, non-ideal characteristics of both opamps cancel each other up to a certain degree. More than that, both opamps should be on a common chip (as identical as possible).

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty close to what I discovered. I didn't consider the opamps being on the same chip.